Can "turns out" be used to talk about past events?
In this video, the speaker said:

It turns out it was designed by a Lithuanian Catholic.

I wonder why he didn't say "turned out". If that means we can use "It turns out" to replace "It turned out" in every situation in the past, it'll be easier for us learners.

No, you can't. The speaker means something like "I have discovered that it was designed by..." with reference to his recent researches. If the relevance of the discovery was in the past, you need the past tense - "I had hoped to see John that day, but it turned out that he had already left".

If we thought previously that something was true, but we have fairly or very recently discovered that it isn't true, we would use the present ('turns'). Everybody thought it was my uncle that shot the neighbours' dog, but it turns out it was my mother.

Thanks, everybody. I hope Michael's example isn't true though.

She was drunk, but that's not really an excuse.

@MichaelHarvey I hope the uncle's shooting of mother wasn't fatal.

@WeatherVane - no, he just winged her, but she plugged him good when she fired back. He's in Boot Hill right now.

If you use it turns out, it means you now know (i.e. recently learned) that such and such is the case.

Everyone thought the fire had to be arson, but it turns out there was an issue with the old wiring.

If you use it turned out you are referring to a time in the past when you learned something you did not previously know, or people generally learned something they did not previously know.

For centuries people thought the world was flat, but as it turned out, the world wasn't flat after all.


In the construction...

It turns out it wasn't true

...the first highlighted element is relative to time of speaking, in exactly the same way as...

I now think it was a lie

